# Liquibase changesets and PostgreSQL JSONB arrow functions

Tags: postgresql, liquibase, jsonb

I have a problem with liquibase and PostgreSQL JSONB arrow functions.
When I trying to use such functions in liquibase changesets, for example:

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_index ON public.foo (bar ->> 'bar');`

I get some:

`liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "->>"`

as a result during compilation. Maybe anybody knows how can such behavior be avoided. (Ignore syntax check or rewrite statement maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_index ON public.foo (bar ->> 'bar');

Expressions need to wrapped in an extra layer of parentheses.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX foo_index ON public.foo ((bar ->> 'bar'));
```

This is purely a PostgreSQL syntax issue, I think liquibase has nothing to do with it.

Comment: This is true. My mistake. Thank you so much.